Counterexample for ideal inclusion when the ring is not finitely generated
This post If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, $I,J,Q$ are its ideals, $Q$ is primary and $IJ \subseteq Q$ , then $I \subseteq Q$ or $J^n \subseteq Q$ for some $n$ gives a statement regarding inclusion of ideals of a Noetherian ring R. What can be a counterexample when R is not finitely generated?

What do you mean by "$R$ finitely generated"? The ring $R$ itself is a finitely generated ideal namely $R = (1)$. Do you mean Noetherian?

Yes, I mean Noetherian.
